# How to get back the last inserted row mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Alright I have been looking for this for a while now, and didn't really found an answer to my problem.

At the moment I got this syntax:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (***, ***, ***, ***) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', %d)", mysql_real_escape_string($***), mysql_real_escape_string($***), mysql_real_escape_string($***), $***);
if(!mysql_query($sql)) { die('error: '.mysql_error()); }
return mysql_insert_id();
```

And this works fine, and when I want to get an item back from the last inserted row I could do another query with the id I get back.

But my question is, is it possible to give back the whole row at once? So that I don't have to run another query to get an item from the last inserted row.

Comment: You want a single function that will return all the values within the record that you just inserted? If so, I don't know of anything built in that will do that.

Comment: Yea thats exactly what i want.

Comment: You could get clever and create a stored procedure or function that will do this for you, but there isn't anything built-in that will help you beyond what you are already using...

Comment: Yea i thought of this also, store the variable before posting and use this further in my script. Kinda more coding but that will help the server load. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,
nothing like that is implemented.

I think it's right, because the [insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) is more complex (see for example `on duplicate key`, `insert ignore`), and in some case the expected return could be ambiguous

Comment: That's what i thought, and was afraid of. Kinda weird though to run 2 query's for such a simple task.

Comment: @Augus - I don't know if it is as simple you you say -as chumkiu alluded. It would have to return the result set dynamically (all the fields that apply) as opposed to a single, integer value (the ID).